# Leftmost-Innermost and Outermost (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I have to show how much steps Haskell needs to calculate (Two ways - leftmost innermost and leftmost outermost). It's for the function

```
minimum [7,4,2,8]
```

Minimum is defined as

```
minimum xs = head (isort xs)
```

So the innermost (?) steps are:

```
1. minimum [7,4,2,8]
2. head (isort [7,4,2,8])
3. head (isort [4,7,2,8])
4. head (isort [2,4,7,8])
5. head [2:4:7:8]
6. (The output) => 2
```

Am I right? I can't see an other way to solve it.. but there should be one..?

(sorry for bad english)..

Thanks for help.

Comment: Hard to tell, since we do not know what `isort`is. And, in addition, in Haskell, you can't choose an evaluation strategy.

Comment: Oh sorry, isort is defined as 
`isort [] = []
isort (a:as) = insert a (isort as)
insert a [] = [a]
insert a (b:as) = if a<=b then a:b:as
else b:(insert a as)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You (probably) forgot

```
4.   head (isort [2,4,7,8])
4.1  head (2 : isort [4,7,8])
4.2  head (2 : 4 : isort [7,8])
4.3  head (2 : 4 : 7 : isort [8])
4.4  head (2 : 4 : 7 : 8 : isort [])
4.4  head (2 : 4 : 7 : 8 : [])
(only now is head's argument a value)
5.   2
```

Through outermost evaluation

```
4.   head (isort [2,4,7,8])
4.1  head (2 : isort [4,7,8])
5    2
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand the difference between innermost and outermost.