# Leftmost-Innermost and Outermost(Haskell)

Tags: list, function, haskell, reduction

I do not understand it well about Reduction in Haskell  in this Function:

```
removeone :: Eq a = > a -> [ a ] -> [ a ]
removeone _ [] = [] 
removeone x ( y : ys ) 
   | x == y  =  removeone x ys
   | otherwise =  y : ( removeone x ys )

remdups :: Eq a = > [ a ] -> [ a ]
remdups [] = []
remdups ( x : xs ) = x : remdups ( removeone x xs )
```

How could I use this function to explain  Reduction steps in a List (for example `remdups [3,7,3,7,5,7]`)?

Comment: Start by `remdups [3,7,3,7,5,7]` and simplify the expression as to the left as possible. Remember that `[x,y,z]` is a shorthand for `x:y:z:[]`. Hence remdups (3:7:....) = 3 : remdups (removeone 3 (7:....)) = ...` and now youl need to use the definition of `removeone` since no equation of `remdups` applies. After `removeone` generates a `:` or `[]`, you will return to simplifying the `remdups` call.

Comment: Start with something easier. For example, try to reduce these functions  in order from harder to easier `reverse`, `(!!)`, `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by `remdups [3,7,3,7,5,7]` and simplify the expression as to the left as possible. Remember that `[x,y,z]` is a shorthand for `x:y:z:[]`. Hence remdups `(3:7:....) = 3 : remdups (removeone 3 (7:....)) = ...` and now youl need to use the definition of `removeone` since no equation of `remdups` applies. After `removeone` generates a `:` or `[]`, you will return to simplifying the `remdups` call.

One row is one reduction. In the comments are row numbers with reduction codes. My example uses a [Outermost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356226/leftmost-innermost-and-outermost-haskell) (lazy) reduction.

```plaintext
remdups [3,7,3,7,5,7]
3:remdups (removeone 3 [7,3,7,5,7]) -- 9
3:remdups (7:(removeone 3 [3,7,5,7])) -- 5
3:7:remdups (removeone 7 (removeone 3 [3,7,5,7])) -- 9
3:7:remdups (removeone 7 (removeone 3 [7,5,7])) -- 4
3:7:remdups (removeone 7 (7:(removeone 3 [5,7]))) -- 5
3:7:remdups (removeone 7 (removeone 3 [5,7])) -- 4
3:7:remdups (removeone 7 (5:(removeone 3 [7]))) -- 5
3:7:remdups (5:(removeone 7 (removeone 3 [7]))) -- 5
3:7:5:remdups (removeone 5 (removeone 7 (removeone 3 [7]))) -- 9
3:7:5:remdups (removeone 5 (removeone 7 (7:(removeone 3 [])))) -- 5
3:7:5:remdups (removeone 5 (removeone 7 (removeone 3 []))) -- 4
3:7:5:remdups (removeone 5 (removeone 7 [])) -- 2
3:7:5:remdups (removeone 5 []) -- 2
3:7:5:remdups [] -- 2
3:7:5:[] -- 8
```

For completeness, there are other reduction procedures. For example leftmost-innermost (greedy) reduction. In this sample is the same result but for example `head $ remdups [1..]` greedy reduction would 'hang'. So as I know, that the leftmost-innermost is used only theoretically or for memory optimization:

```plaintext
remdups [3,7,3,7,5,7]
3:remdups (removeone 3 [7,3,7,5,7])
3:remdups (7:(removeone 3 [3,7,5,7]))
3:remdups (7:(removeone 3 [7,5,7]))
3:remdups (7:(7:(removeone 3 [5,7])))
3:remdups (7:(7:(5:(removeone 3 [7]))))
3:remdups (7:(7:(5:(7:(removeone 3 [])))))
3:remdups (7:(7:(5:(7:([])))))
3:remdups [7,7,5,7] -- shorthand
3:7:remdups (removeone 7 [7,5,7])
3:7:remdups (removeone 7 [5,7])
3:7:remdups (5:(removeone 7 [7]))
3:7:remdups (5:(removeone 7 []))
3:7:remdups (5:([]))
3:7:remdups [5] -- shorthand
3:7:5:remdups (removeone 5 [])
3:7:5:remdups ([])
3:7:5:remdups [] -- shorthand
3:7:5:[]
[3,7,5] -- shorthand
```

Comment: so is this the Leftmost-Innermost or the Outermost reduction?

Comment: @WillNess I tried it in GHCI, and it reduced the formula like that. It should be a lazy reduction.  It is the [Outermost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356226/leftmost-innermost-and-outermost-haskell).

Comment: I meant, this should be mentioned in the answer. BTW the Q asks for both. :)

Answer (score 2):

In pseudocode, we have

```
rem1 x (x:t)  =   rem1 x t
rem1 x (a:t)  = a:rem1 x t                    ;  rem1 x [] = []

remdups (a:t) = a:remdups (rem1 a t)          ;  remdups [] = []
```

Innermost-Leftmost (eager evaluation):

```
remdups               [3,7,3,7,5,7]
= 3:  remdups   (rem1 3 [7,3,7,5,7])
= 3:  remdups   (7:rem1 3 [3,7,5,7])
= 3:  remdups   (7:  rem1 3 [7,5,7])
= 3:  remdups   (7:7:  rem1 3 [5,7])
= 3:  remdups   (7:7:5:  rem1 3 [7])
= 3:  remdups   (7:7:5:7: rem1 3 [])
= 3:  remdups   (7:7:5:7: []       )
= 3: 7:  remdups  (rem1 7 (7:5:7:[]))
= 3: 7:  remdups  (  rem1 7 (5:7:[]))
= 3: 7:  remdups  (  5:rem1 7 (7:[]))
= 3: 7:  remdups  (  5:  rem1 7 ([]))
= 3: 7:  remdups  (  5:  []         )
= 3: 7: 5:  remdups  (rem1 5     [] )
= 3: 7: 5:  remdups  []
= 3: 7: 5: []       -- 15 reductions
```

Outermost (what Haskell is doing):

```
remdups                               [3,7,3,7,5,7]
= 3:                   remdups  (rem1 3 [7,3,7,5,7])
= 3:                   remdups  (7:rem1 3 [3,7,5,7])
= 3: 7:          remdups  (rem1 7 (rem1 3 [3,7,5,7]))
= 3: 7:          remdups  (rem1 7 (  rem1 3 [7,5,7]))
= 3: 7:          remdups  (rem1 7 (7:  rem1 3 [5,7]))
= 3: 7:          remdups  (rem1 7 (    rem1 3 [5,7]))
= 3: 7:          remdups  (rem1 7 (   5: rem1 3 [7]))
= 3: 7:          remdups  (5:rem1 7 (    rem1 3 [7]))
= 3: 7: 5: remdups  (rem1 5 (rem1 7 (    rem1 3 [7])))
= 3: 7: 5: remdups  (rem1 5 (rem1 7 ( 7: rem1 3  [])))
= 3: 7: 5: remdups  (rem1 5 (rem1 7 (    rem1 3  [])))
= 3: 7: 5: remdups  (rem1 5 (rem1 7      []         ))
= 3: 7: 5: remdups  (rem1 5 []                       )
= 3: 7: 5: remdups  []   
= 3: 7: 5: []       -- 15 reductions
```